# Mongo delete_many method does not remove document from db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm trying to delete a MongoDb database document from Rails.

According to the [mongodb docs](http://api.mongodb.com/ruby/current/Mongo/Collection.html#delete_many-instance_method), this is the way to do it:

```
db = Mongoid::Clients.default
collection = db[:oauth_access_tokens]
collection.delete_many({"resource_owner_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx"})
```

Based on the result I get it should be fine:

```
<Mongo::Operation::Result:58395820 documents=[{"ok"=>1, "n"=>0, "opTime"=>{"ts"=>#<BSON::Timestamp:0x00000006f62380 @seconds=1500457271, @increment=1>, "t"=>2}, "electionId"=>BSON::ObjectId('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx')}]>
```

But then if I find in the mongo shell:

```
db.oauth_access_tokens.find({resource_owner_id: ObjectId("00000111111")})
```

I still get the document when I should not.

Comment: Your result says `"n"=>0` which means there are no matching documents to remove. If `resource_owner_id` is of ObjectID type, make sure you send ObjectID in the `delete_many` filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
collection.delete_many(:resource_owner_id => BSON::ObjectId("00000111111"))
```